# How to pass magickWand reference to functions

Tags: go, imagemagick, magickwand

May I know how to pass `imagick.MagickWand` struct to functions and apply it methods on it? It seems that the `imagick.NewMagickWand` return the type of `*imagick.MagickWand`, isn't it?

I can't get it done, keep getting the error message: *ERROR_WAND: ContainsNoImages `MagickWand-0'*.

How to pass proper struct reference to the function so that the `mw` can be continuously **used** in those functions?

```
func generateImage() error {
    // skip error handling
    var err error 

    mw := imagick.NewMagickWand()
    defer mw.Destroy()

    err = createCanvas(mw, "red") // create canvas
    err = compositeIcon(mw, "c:/icon.png") // add icon
    err = addText(mw, "Hello world") // add text

    err = mw.WriteImage("c:/output") // get the output
}

func createCanvas(mw *imagick.MagickWand, color string) error {
    // skip error handling
    var err error
    pw := imagick.NewPixelWand()
    defer pw.Destroy()

    pw.SetColor("blue")
    err = mw.NewImage(200, 100, pw)
    return nil
}
```

May please help? Newbie here. :)

---

**Update:**

> The example that I gave is **correct**. Passing by reference is done correctly in the **example above**, I received the error because I *overlook* my code and debug the wrong lines. Sorry for confusion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `mw` has type `*imagick.MagickWand` then `*mw` has type `imagick.MagickWand`.

That is to say, `mw` is a *pointer* to that type and the `*` operator dereferences the pointer to the *type itself*.

```
mw := imagick.NewMagickWand() // Now mw is a *imagick.MagickWand
*mw // Is a imagick.MagickWand
```

Comment: so, i declare the function as `createCanvas(mw *imagick.MagickWand)`, and inside the function, I use the `mw` as if `err = *mw.NewImage(200,100,pw)`? Trying now... :)

Comment: receive error message: `createCanvas passes lock by value: .../imagick.v3/imagick.MagickWand contains sync.Once contains sync.Mutex`... I try to change the `*` position around the code, but can't get it done.

Comment: Thanks for helping. What you said is correct... After careful examination, I notice I naively debug the wrong line. Thanks.